# Finding the Angle theta between two 2d vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the angle α between the vectors $$\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}and \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

I found 64.654, but apparently is wrong from what the webwork says. Can anyone check if they get the same answer ? or the calculation i should be using.

Comment: That's what I get too (in degrees). You may want to answer in radians.

Comment: @mrf, I converted to radian with google, I get 0.0174532925 which is wrong. Also tried setting my calculator to radians and the number 1.13 which is also wrong Y_Y becoming desperate

Comment: Two professional mathematicians already told you that you're right, Reza, so odds are **you** are right and the book is wrong. Believe me, this happens way more times than beginner students seem to be ready to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the vectors are "anchored" at the origin and that we have the usual inner product in $\,\Bbb R^2\,$ , we get that the wanted angle $\,\theta\,$ is given by

$$\cos\theta=\frac{\binom{3}{5}\cdot\binom{-2}{3}}{\left|\left|\binom{3}{5}\right|\right|\;\left|\left|\binom{-2}{3}\right|\right|}=\frac{-6+15}{\sqrt{34}\sqrt{13}}=\frac{9}{\sqrt{442}}\Longrightarrow \theta=\arccos\frac{9}{\sqrt{442}}=64.65^\circ$$

and thus your answer is correct...unless the assumptions in the first part are different, of course.

Another possibility is they want the angle in radians, so after the known conversion it'd be $\,\theta=1.13\,$ radians

Comment: I tried the radian value as well, and both are wrong T_T

Comment: Well Reza, another very possible option is that the webwork is wrong...;)

Comment: alright, ty, won't waste further time on it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \|u\| \|v\| \cos \theta$$

The dot product is 9, and magnitudes are $\sqrt{34}$ and $\sqrt{13}$, so

$$\cos \theta = \frac{9}{\sqrt{34 \cdot 13}}$$

so $\theta = \arccos \frac{9}{\sqrt{34 \cdot 13}} = 64.65$ degrees...

Comment: Can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Hello: you can use the dot product between vectors

$\theta = \arccos(\frac{3\cdot(-2)+5\cdot(3)}{\sqrt{(3^2+5^2)(2^2+3^3)}})$

if you use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Carccos%28%5Cfrac%7B3%5Ccdot%28-2%29%2B5%5Ccdot%283%29%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%283%5E2%2B5%5E2%29%282%5E2%2B3%5E3%29%7D%7D%29) for to get the result

Ans: $\theta = 1.2898983977450732031495202240229012130410696446569681$

Comment: The value still wrong. I'm just going to speak to the teacher. Thanks.

Comment: This computation is incorrect

Comment: It's not $3^3$ but $3^2$ in the denominator's right factor under the square root....