# Calculate the angle between two vectors when direction is important

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[Calculate the angle between two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317874/calculate-the-angle-between-two-vectors?rq=1) 
is very similar but I don't manage to adapt to my case. obvious mathematics aren't my strong area.

[image]

First I define my vectors like:

```
V1 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) 
V2 = (x2, y2, x3, y3)
```

For A:

```
V1 = (-3, -3, 2, 2)
V2 = (2, 2, 6, -3)
```

So need to convert to:

```
V1 = (x1, y1) 
V2 = (x2, y2)
```

And second I need the counter clockwise angle to be between 0 and 360 instead of (-180, 180).

So I need the angle but depend on where they join to indicate if I have to add 180 or not.

If I use `A.B = |A||B| cos(angle)` always get the smaller angle.

Answer (score 2):

For the two vectors $v_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $v_2 = (x_2,\;y_2)$ the oriented angle  between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is
$$\angle(v_1, v_2) = \mathrm{atan2}\left(x_1y_2-y_1x_2,\;x_1x_2+y_1y_2\right)$$
where $\mathrm{atan2(y,x)}$ is the two argument $\arctan$
from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2.
You can find the formula in this answer to the linked 
[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047350/61216). For more accurate (and more complicated) formulas in extreme cases, see "A uniformly accurate arctan(…) formula for the angle between two vectors" by 
[W. Kahan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf), page 15, Kahan's formulas are valid for higher dimensions.

Example: For your red vector $v_1=(1,2)$ and the green $v_2=(1,-2)$ you compute
$$\angle(v_1, v_2) = -1.107  = -63.44°,$$ this
is roughly your left picture and for you second case 
$$\angle(v_1, -v_2)= 0.5880 = 33.68°.$$

Comment: I want something like ~30 for the first one and ~30 + 180 for the second one

Comment: Then you have a different definition of vector, as normally the arrows start in the origin.

Comment: That is the first part of my question. My vectors are (x1,y1,x2,y2)

Comment: What are the numbers for your examples?

Comment: I add one example on the question. But use 90 for simplicity.

Comment: This does not look like your picture, I would expect `V2 = (2, 2, 7, -3) `.

Comment: yes, last one was supposed to be negative