# Angle between two vectors, where am I wrong?

Tags: geometry

I am facing a problem, I want to find the angle between the vector u and the vector v, here is what I am doing to get this angle (I used [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310653/finding-the-angle-theta-between-two-2d-vectors)) :
[image]
So what I am finding is an angle that is about 1.23 radians or 70.5° (btw sorry for comma instead of the points, I am french). The problem is that when I reproduce the figure with GeoGebra, I have got this :
[image]
So the angle is clearly not 70.5°... **where am I wrong ?**
(the vector u have (2;1) coordinates and the vector w (v on Geogebra) have (1;3) coordinates)

Comment: everywhere? ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec{u}\cdot \vec{w} = 2\times 1 + 1 \times 3$ then that implies that $\vec{u} = (2,1)$ and $\vec{w}=(1,3)$.

If that is the case then $\|\vec{w}\| = \sqrt{1^2+3^1} = \sqrt{10}$ and not $\sqrt{45}$ as you seem to think.

From your calculation that $\|\vec{w}\| = \sqrt{3^2+(-6)^2}$, I assume that $\vec{w} = (3,-6)$.

Is $\vec{w} = (1,3)$ or is $\vec{w}=(3,-6)$?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot ! I just completely confused the different values ! I'll accept your answer when I will be able to !

Comment: Actually, w = (1,3) this is where I dit my error ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise No worries. I'm glad that I could help :o)

Answer (score 1):

$$|W|=\sqrt{3^2+1^2}=\sqrt{10}$$
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{10} \sqrt{5}}\right)=45 {}^{\circ}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! You just showed me where I was wrong !